# Nginx URL rewriting issue

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I need help with nginx rewriting. I have a script which is running as follows

```
http://domain.com:2095/secretkey/something
```

Now above command takes user ip address automatically and I want to rewrite as follows

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/secretkey/something
```

I am using following rule but it is not working.

```
 server
{
listen ip:443;
server_name subdomain.domain.com
location / { 
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr break; 
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2095; }
}
```

Comment: Your `server_name` is `subdomain.domain.com`, it will never process a request to `domain.com:2095`.  To be fair, i'm clueless about what you actually want.  What does the user actually type in his her browser address bar?  I have the impression that you do not need `rewrite` at all.